# How to resolve “Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean” java error?

Tags: java, return

When I'm trying to run one of the examples on the book I get an error which I don't know how to fix. The code is:

```
class Xcopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int org = 42;
        Xcopy x = new Xcopy();
        int y = x.jazda(org);
        System.out.println(org + " " + y);
    }
    void jazda(int arg) {
        arg = arg * 2;
        return arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void jazda(int arg)` -> `int jazda(int arg)`

Comment: even the error message seems to be wrong... or is the code `boolean jazda(...`?  anyway Erans [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422986/how-to-resolve-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-int-to-boolean-java-error#comment117427654_66422986) should solve it (and I cannot upvote it :-))

Answer (score 1):

Your method ***jazda*** is of type void and returns ***int***.

```
class Xcopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int org = 42;
        Xcopy x = new Xcopy();
        int y = x.jazda(org);
        System.out.println(org + " " + y);
    }
    void jazda(int arg) { //you declare returning type of method to void
        arg = arg * 2;
        return arg; //you return int
    }
}
```

You need to change type of method ***jazda*** to ***int***.

```
class Xcopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int org = 42;
        Xcopy x = new Xcopy();
        int y = x.jazda(org);
        System.out.println(org + " " + y);
    }
    int jazda(int arg) { //changed return type to int
        arg = arg * 2;
        return arg;
    }
}
```

Now all methods and variables got corresponding types.